# Getting image resolution in ERDAS

Tags: image, erdas-imagine, resolution

How can I know image resolution of an image in ERDAS?

[image]

Comment: Read the values of Pixel Sixe X and Pixel Size Y.

Comment: I'm new to GIS and geography, so can you please explain more?

Comment: One pixel is 30 meters high and 30 meters wide.